# Can I use Yellow Croaker for fish and chips?

Tags: fish, deep-frying

I bought some fish called Yellow Croaker. Can this be fried with batter to make fish and chips or will this type of fish not have the right type of texture for fried fish?

What type of fish is traditionally used to make fish and chips, and generally what type of characteristics in fish would make it a good candidate to be used as a fried fish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally any non-oily fish is fine for deep frying. A relatively meaty fish (though not too meaty like monkfish) with a good thick fillet is best, because this allows the batter to cook without overcooking the fish. As Yellow Croaker is not an oily fish, you should be fine to batter and deep fry it provided you have a nice thick fillet.

Traditional fish and chips usually uses cod or haddock.